# Reactively write to redis in `REDISJSON` format

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce, redisjson

I am using ReactiveRedisOperations with the driver of lettuce to write to Redis.

```java
@Autowired
ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Foo> redisOperation;

public Mono<Boolean> save(Foo foo) {
    redisOperation.map(operation -> 
     operation
     .opsForValue()
     .set(foo.getId(), foo);

    return Mono.just(true);
}
```

The serialization is defined as

```java
    private <T> ReactiveRedisOperations<String, T> buildRedisOperations(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory, Class<T> clazz) {
        RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, T> builder = RedisSerializationContext
                .newSerializationContext(new StringRedisSerializer());
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<T> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(clazz);
        RedisSerializationContext<String, T> context = builder.value(serializer).build();
        return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
    }
```

This works however the data type of the `Foo` object is saved as `String`. I want to save the Foo object in `Redisjson` datatype.

How to use reactively write to redis and save in [REDISJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) format?

PS: I dont want to use `lua script` solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

**ReactiveRedisOperations** are meant for **basic** redis operations only (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ReactiveRedisOperations.html).

If you want to continue using lettuce along with reactive operations, use https://github.com/redis-developer/lettucemod instead.

This library provides RedisJSON support

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to initialize a dedicate `ReactiveRedisTemplate` bean for `Foo` class?

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Foo> reactiveRedisTemplate(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, Foo> builder = RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(new StringRedisSerializer());
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Foo> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Foo.class);
    RedisSerializationContext<String, Foo> context = builder.value(serializer).build();
    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
}
```

And use it to store values in Redis.

```
@Autowired
ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Foo> reactiveRedisTemplate;

public Mono<Boolean> save(Foo foo) {
    return reactiveRedisTemplate
          .opsForValue()
          .set(foo.getId(), foo);
}
```

Comment: "I want to save the Foo object in Redisjson datatype." obviously this is going to save it as a string.